# Improve a bash script

Tags: python, bash, dockerfile

Here's a little bash script I wrote, which basically checks something on an Amazon EC2 instance and reports data to CloudWatch every 60 seconds. I'll run this in a container. Everything works just fine, but I think it's clunky and doesn't handle any errors. I am open to refactoring this or even writing it in Python, to make my docker image more efficient. Any suggestions, criticism is most welcome.

Here's the full script.

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTANCEID=`curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/`
AZ=`curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
REGION="`echo \"$AZ\" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
URL= XXXX

putdata()
{
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-data XXXXX
    sleep 60
}
while true
    do
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $URL)
        if [ "$HTTP_RESPONSE" = "200" ]; then
        putdata 0 

    else
        putdata 1 

    fi
done
```

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: nice, i didn't know that Omair, thanks.

Comment: Install and use a shell script linter. Your shell script generates 10 warnings, for example. For example: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: gotcha, will do that

Comment: @jarmod which one do you use?

Comment: The one indicated: shellcheck. You can typically integrate linting with your code editor.